# Just had a suggested edit with no visible edit

Tags: discussion, feature-request, suggested-edits

I was going through the suggested edit queue and came across [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8068412) to [Java applet pack200 gets gz version of CRL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29534675/java-applet-pack200-gets-gz-version-of-crl).  The editor put in a comment for the edit that they are having the same problem.  I scrolled through the edit to find out what they edited and I can't find anything they changed.  I then changed from rendered output to markdown and I was able to see they added a blank line to the beginning of the question.

Is there something we can do about this?  If suggested edits must have at least 6 characters can't we change that they must be visible characters or if they are white space then it should only count in code blocks for people who are fixing indentation.

Comment: It's not really as trivial as you might think to determine what changes in whitespace are fixing formatting problems and which are just making invisible edits.

Comment: @Servy: It's very easy: Just compare the rendered output pixel by pixel to each other ;)

Comment: @honk Then of course they add one normal space in addition to all of the invisible characters....

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Normally an edit *has* to change six non-whitespace characters, so the likelihood is that there were six non-printable characters edited in.

In this scenario, the edit wouldn't have *hurt* anything, but more importantly it didn't *help* anything, so it was correctly rejected.

What we can do:  if you encounter a suggested edit like this in the future, reject it.  Edits that don't improve content aren't worth it.

Comment: If they were non-printable characters then should there possibly be a check for these characters when suggesting edit? That way it can be prevented before the edit goes to the queue.

Comment: The suggested-edits page has 25 spaces (0x20) as the only detected change in the edit.  Either the input was changed after the character limit was applied, or there is an issue which needs to be looked into.

Answer (score -27):

@Makato et al...I'm not one of the writers or editors, just a humble ask-a-few questions, read-a-lot, and try to learn something guy.  I know all of your hearts are in the right place.  I've dealt with PITA editors and the like.  One of the things I've learned over the years is content is only half the battle.  You can provide all the great content to people you can.  However, if the audience has obstacles because of formatting or style somesuch, it is material.

Enough of my soapbox.  Here's a suggestion:  Why not have two series of editting/feedback.  The first covers content and correctness.  Once that is locked down you can have a round of making-it-pretty...and (s)he-who-is-in-charge has final say.  Lay down those rules ahead of time.  Let 'em know what they are.  Let 'em have their input...then yer done.

That's my 2-cents...49 more times and ya got yourself some folding money!

Comment: There isn't really any "done" with a wiki-style system, like SO uses. Content and formatting are both always open for (useful) editing, and there's no particular reason to lock things down in a hardcoded two-cycle system.

Comment: @BiggerDon, I think you misread the question.  The edit wasn't meant to change anything, content **or** formatting.  It was just a bizarrely creative attempt to get around the minimum reputation limit for posting comments so he could post exactly the kind of comment the limit was meant to prevent.

Comment: OK...I got dinged.  I'm a bad bad man...maybe I'll do it right this time.  :)
Alan and @Nathan ....

Thanks for the explanations. Now I understand what kind of articles (Wiki v. "papers"), and why people are doing these things. Perhaps a reputation points penalty should be incurred for non-substantive edits. I know, I know...That's another ugly can of worms.

Comment: You sound very much like Lt Columbo to me, can't imagine all this being said with any other voice.

Comment: As a multi-decade fan, I take that as a great compliment!